# Finding 301 Redirects which are working on my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have reached a fair number of redirects in the .htaccess of web site (around 700) due to software upgrades. I think about half of these have been now indexed by Google. How can I find the list of redirects which are currently being used ? 
My idea is to find all "301" in the Apache Logs, such as this:

> 1.235.117.180 - - [01/Aug/2014:06:41:59 +0200] "GET /components/com_acesearch/assets/css/acesearch.css HTTP/1.1" **301** 626
>   "http://example.com/link1/link2/page-2" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125
>   Safari/537.36"

Is it safe to assume that all Redirects which are not listed like the above one are not being used (so I can remove them?) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not safe, do not rely only on the apache logs. Some old links might still be in the index and can be crawled later on.

Can't you optimize your redirects? Can you give an example of some of the redirects? Isn't there a pattern? With regular expressions, you can rewrite your files quite effectively if you can find a sort of pattern (or a couple of them).

There are more search engines than Google alone. If it is important that everything keeps indexed, I would keep the redirects, but find the pattern and schrink the number of redirects to max. 10 or something.

Comment: Thanks. Well some of the redirects have been already optimized, however most of them cannot easily be optimized as the pattern for the new link has changed a lot. Maybe I'll post some of them on the .htaccess mailing list

Comment: ok, you could also rewrite all non-existing files to a php file which handles all the 301-redirects, and stores the request in a database, so that you can easily find out which old urls are still in use, and which search engine they originate from. This will be a little less performant, but they are still 'old' links...